# Set multiple column classes from a vector in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking for some guidance on how I might assign column classes to a data.table when there are multiple classes. So for example if I just want to assign one it is fairly straight forward:

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(iris)
str(dt)
#> Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
#>  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#>  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#>  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#>  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#>  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>

dtnew <- dt[, lapply(.SD, as.character )]
str(dtnew)
#> Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
#>  $ Sepal.Length: chr  "5.1" "4.9" "4.7" "4.6" ...
#>  $ Sepal.Width : chr  "3.5" "3" "3.2" "3.1" ...
#>  $ Petal.Length: chr  "1.4" "1.4" "1.3" "1.5" ...
#>  $ Petal.Width : chr  "0.2" "0.2" "0.2" "0.2" ...
#>  $ Species     : chr  "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" ...
#>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Consider though the scenario where one might have a vector of column class like this:

```
col_classes <- c('character', 'character', 'numeric', 'factor', 'character')
```

I'd like to apply those column class to the `dt` object but am struggling with the appropriate way to do this in data.table.

Thanks in advance.

<sup>Created on 2019-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Two great answer below. I think a little benchmarking to determine which approach to take:

```r
library(data.table)


## options
foo <- function(d, col_classes) {
  cc <- setNames(col_classes, names(d))
  res = lapply(setNames(, names(cc)), function(n) match.fun(sprintf("as.%s", cc[[n]]))(d[[n]]))

  setDT(res)[]
}

bar <- function(d, col_classes) {
  d[, setNames(Map(function(x, y) match.fun(x)(y), paste0("as.", col_classes), .SD), names(d))]
}

## Attempt one
dt <- as.data.table(iris)


col_classes <- c('character', 'character', 'numeric', 'factor', 'character')

bench::mark(
  foo(dt, col_classes),
  bar(dt, col_classes),
  iterations = 10
)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   expression                min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>           <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 foo(dt, col_classes)  553.2us  594.3us      799.    1.64MB      0  
#> 2 bar(dt, col_classes)   1.07ms   1.82ms      407.  365.71KB     45.2




number_of_rows <- 1E7 ## way increase this to really test this out

## Create fake data
fake_data <- data.table(sample(1:100, number_of_rows, replace=TRUE),
                       sample(1900:2000, number_of_rows, replace = TRUE),
                       sample(c("MALE", "FEMALE"), number_of_rows, replace = TRUE),
                       sample(c("E", "M", "H"), number_of_rows, replace = TRUE))
colnames(fake_data) <- c("RAW_SCORE", "BIRTHYEAR", "TYPE", "CLASS")


col_classes <- c('numeric', 'character', 'factor', 'factor')

bench::mark(
  foo(fake_data, col_classes),
  bar(fake_data, col_classes), 
  iterations = 10
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   expression                       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>                  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 foo(fake_data, col_classes)    4.72s    7.34s     0.143     943MB    0.357
#> 2 bar(fake_data, col_classes)     7.2s    7.62s     0.131    1019MB    0.368
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same idea as @RonakShah's answer but assuming the OP has explicitly named the columns rather than passing by position:

```
# different input format
cc <- setNames(col_classes, names(dtnew)) 

# usage
res = lapply(setNames(, names(cc)), function(n) 
  match.fun(sprintf("as.%s", cc[[n]]))(dtnew[[n]])
)
setDT(res)[]
```

Some other ways the problem might be solved:

- If reading the data in, use the `colClasses=` argument to `fread()` or a similar function.
- Maybe also consider `type.convert` which will automatically guess and apply a class to each column. It cannot return a mix of character and factor columns, however.

Answer (score 4):

Convert `col_classes` to function names, match them with `match.fun` and apply to every column

```
dt_temp <- dtnew[, setNames(Map(function(x, y) match.fun(x)(y), 
                   paste0("as.", col_classes), .SD), names(dtnew))]

str(dt_temp)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ Sepal.Length: chr  "5.1" "4.9" "4.7" "4.6" ...
# $ Sepal.Width : chr  "3.5" "3" "3.2" "3.1" ...
# $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
# $ Petal.Width : Factor w/ 22 levels "0.1","0.2","0.3",..: 2 2 2 2 2 4 3 2 2 1 ...
# $ Species     : chr  "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" ...
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

PS - There must be a better way to retain the column names instead of using `setNames`.

Comment: Imo, OP should explicitly name the columns in the input vector rather than pass by position, so `cc <- setNames(col_classes, names(dtnew))` in which case your answer becomes `res = lapply(setNames(, names(cc)), function(n) match.fun(sprintf("as.%s", cc[[n]]))(dtnew[[n]])); setDT(res)[]`

Comment: I did some benchmarking which I posted to the answer. They doesn't appear to be a performance cost with @Frank2 answer. If he wants to post that as an answer I'd accept that.